# FATAL EXCEPTION: Retrofit-Idle in Retrofit 1.9.0 before call `failure` callback in @FormUrlEncoded api method

Tags: android, retrofit

I have a method in retrofit api interface like this.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/token")
void generateToken( @Field("username") String user, @Field("password") String password,
                    @Field("grant_type") String grantType, Callback<JsonObject> callback);
```

I call it in my login Activity by `api.generateToken(userName, userPassword, GRANT_TYPE, getLoginCallback(button));`

The method `getLoginCallback()` returns and callback. Check below:

```
private Callback<JsonObject> getLoginCallback(final Button button){
    return new Callback<JsonObject>() {

        @Override
        public void success(JsonObject jsonObject, Response response) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            populateToken(jsonObject.toString());
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            String toastErrorMessage = "Erro de login";
            toastMessage(toastErrorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

            dismissDialog();
            button.setEnabled(true);

        }
    };
}
```

When I get a ok result, everything works as it suppose to.

But when it get error, instead of executing `failure` method of my callback, it's throwing the follow error in a not UI Thread.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Retrofit-Idle
Process: neocom.dealerbook, PID: 5782
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Throwable.getMessage()' on a null object reference
at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:50)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I've tried older version of retrofit (1.8.0), same thing.
I've debugged into retrofit code, found that it call a errorHandler.handleError in CllbackRunnable that returns null.

```
try {
  final ResponseWrapper wrapper = obtainResponse();
  callbackExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
      callback.success((T) wrapper.responseBody, wrapper.response);
    }
  });
} catch (RetrofitError e) {
  Throwable cause = errorHandler.handleError(e);
  final RetrofitError handled = cause == e ? e : unexpectedError(e.getUrl(), cause);
  callbackExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
      callback.failure(handled);
    }
  });
}
```

}

It throws the error when calling `unexpectedError(e.getUrl(), cause);`
The value of `e` at this time is `retrofit.RetrofitError: 400 Bad Request`

Here is `unexpectedError` method

```
public class RetrofitError extends RuntimeException {

// ...

    public static RetrofitError unexpectedError(String url, Throwable exception) {
        return new RetrofitError(exception.getMessage(), url, null, null, null, Kind.UNEXPECTED,exception);
    }

// ...
}
```

### Update: Partial Solution

What I've done till now is, instead of calling `api.generateToken(userName, userPassword, GRANT_TYPE, getLoginCallback(button));` I created a synchronous method in Retrofit's API interface.

So I did all thread control by myself. This way I have control of what gone wrong.

So now I'm using a method like this in Api:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/token")
JsonObject generateToken( @Field("username") String user, @Field("password") String password,
                    @Field("grant_type") String grantType);
```

Then at my *Activity* I created two methods, one that tries to get the token by Api.generateToken method in a new Thread and a method that is called if catches a exception. Here it follows:

```
private void tryLogin(final Button button, final String userName, final String userPassword) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                API api = ApiFactory.getApi();
                JsonObject response = api.generateToken(userName, userPassword, GRANT_TYPE);
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                populateToken(response.toString());
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } catch (RetrofitError |IllegalStateException e){
                loginFail(button);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

private void loginFail(final Button button) {
    button.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            String toastErrorMessage = "Erro de login";
            toastMessage(toastErrorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

            dismissDialog();
            button.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
}
```

So when user touches Login button, I'm calling `tryLogin(button, userName, userPassword);` instead of `api.generateToken(userName, userPassword, GRANT_TYPE, getLoginCallback(button));`

I still want to know a better solution, or if I'm doing something wrong that's making Retrofit crash. But for now I solved my problem.

Comment: You should check `if (e != null)` before you go using any methods on `e`

Comment: @cricket_007 this last pice of code is from Retrofit, It was decompiled by Android Studio. So it's not under my control.

Comment: It's not clear in your stacktrace where the null value is coming from, but it is from one of the `RetrofitError`s